Merging Alias Data in Grafana
I have Zabbix feeding into Grafana a set of data, which is then Alias and grouped by the Alias,
however Grafana is still displaying the items as separate, although the values are grouped.
This is a per minute check returning data as below:
host: title: \[company1|1210|-1|1|58|0|4|0\] end text host: title: \[company2|1210|-1|1|58|0|5|0\] end text host: title: \[company2|1210|1|1|40|0|4|0\] end text
The Alias is then set on check using (?<=\|)(\d{4})(?=\|)
so that Grafana then only displays the 4 digit number.
The issue I am having is even when using "group by" transformation and selecting the 1210 item,
The values in the graph all match, but the legend is still displaying 3 separate items
The screen snip attached shows how this is presenting, I'm struggling to get just one entered item per 4 digit variable. even though the values are being matched by the Group Transform.
(https://i.sstatic.net/oJ1nssYA.png)
Any help would be appreciated.
